# React Navigation route.params typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm creating a Expo managed React Native app with TypeScript and having some problems with React Navigation and TypeScript.

I want to specify the icon for the Bottom Tab Navigator on the Tab.Screen component.

This code works but complains because route.params could be undefined (line 10).

*Property 'icon' does not exist on type 'object'*

Can I make the icon prop required on initialParams?

I have looked in the documentation without any luck.

```
const App: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
            tabBarIcon: ({ size, color }) => (
              <MaterialIcons
                size={size}
/* ===> */      name={route.params.icon}
                color={color}
              />
            ),
          })}
        >
          <Tab.Screen
            name="EventListView"
            initialParams={{ icon: 'view-agenda' }}
            component={EventListScreen}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="CreateEvent"
            initialParams={{ icon: 'public' }}
            component={SettingsScreen}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 60):

`import { RouteProp } from '@react-navigation/native';`

```
  route: RouteProp<{ params: { icon: ICON_TYPE } }, 'params'>
```

I recently had the same issue, I came up with this, it seems to be working fine.

Comment: You're rock man! thank you so much! Looking for this for a long time

Comment: It's a workaround for typing. Not a real solution (if you change your route param name, TS would not warn you about it, due to static typing on screen)

Answer (score 17):

It is now pretty well explained in the official doc.
Working well.

Read the doc: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#type-checking-the-navigator

Here a quick look of how it could look like:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

type RootStackParamList = {
   Home: undefined;
   Profile: { userId: string };
   Feed: { sort: 'latest' | 'top' } | undefined;
};

const RootStack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();

<RootStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
   <RootStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
   <RootStack.Screen
      name="Profile"
      component={Profile}
      initialParams={{ userId: user.id }}
   />
   <RootStack.Screen name="Feed" component={Feed} />
</RootStack.Navigator>
```

Then to type check your component:

```
interface Props extends NativeStackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Profile'> {
    // other props ...
}

const ProfileScreen: React.FC<Props> = ({ route, navigation }) => {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The right way of doing this would be to define a type with the params, and send that as the type argument when creating the navigator. Something like this:

```
type TabNavigatorParamList = {
  EventListView: { icon: string }
  CreateEvent: { icon: string }
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator<TabNavigatorParamList>(); //*
```

`*` I've assumed your Tab component was a BottomTabNavigator, but the same code would work no matter what kind of `create{whatever}Navigator` you use.

Just like that your `Tab.Navigator` and `Tab.Screen` will have the right type for their `route` prop.

There's more info [in the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#nesting-navigators), and more advanced situations like annotating hooks and nested navigators.